# how to fix unexpected token parsing error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-modules

The arrow works for me all time but i get an error now `Parsing error: Unexpected token =>`
I tried checking the syntax and bracket and yeah, I dint miss any brackets.

Code :

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const Filter = require("bad-words");

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.detectEvilUsers = functions.firestore
  .document("messages/{msgId}")
  .onCreate(async (doc, ctx) => {
    const filter = new Filter();
    const { text, uid } = doc.data();

    if (filter.isProfane(text)) {
      const cleaned = filter.clean(text);
      await doc.ref.update({
        text: "I got banned for lifetime for using voilated words",
      });

      await db.collection("banned").doc(uid).set({});
    }
  });
```

Error :

> Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

And If try to change it to normal function(){} call, like this

```
exports.detectEvilUsers = functions.firestore
  .document("messages/{msgId}")
  .onCreate(async function(doc, ctx)  {
        const filter = new Filter();
        const { text, uid } = doc.data();
    ....
    ....
    ....
    }
```

It gives me `Parsing error:unexpected token function`

Comment: What is your environment? Node?

Comment: any log explaining line number ?

Comment: @TJ 14.5 ..............

Comment: @SarveshMahajan Yeah, It says Parsing error: Unexpected token =>

Comment: Yeah I have .eslintrc.json file ,, module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "google",
  ],
  rules: {
    quotes: ["error", "double"],
  },
};

Comment: yes I have, I posted in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eslin.json file:
`{ "parser": "babel-eslint", "plugins": [ "babel" ], "extends": [ "plugin:prettier/recommended", "plugin:react/recommended" ], "env": { "browser": true, "es6": true, "jest": true }, "parserOptions": { "ecmaVersion": 2018, "sourceType": "module", "ecmaFeatures": { "jsx": true } }, "rules": { "curly": "error", "eqeqeq": "error", "guard-for-in": "error", "no-extend-native": "error", "complexity": [ "error", 200 ], "max-depth": [ "error", 5 ], "max-params": [ "error", 12 ], "max-statements": [ "error", 200 ], "no-caller": "error", "no-irregular-whitespace": "error", "no-new": "error", "no-undef": "error", "no-unused-vars": "error", "no-global-assign": "error", "react/prop-types": "off", "babel/semi": 1 } }`

Comment: Yeah this worked :) But may I know my Eslin.json file dint work.

Comment: some attributes might be missing in your case. Kindly accept the answer if it help, thanks in advance buddy